# CSS progress bar width set by inline style, not being applied

Tags: css, progress-bar, drupal-9

My CSS progress bar renders everything except the inline style is not applied so the size of the progress contents does not dynamically change as expected.  The value of {{ field_ct_rack_left_pdu__value }} is pushed from a Drupal View.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="iab-progress-bar" data-label="{{ field_ct_rack_left_pdu__value }}%" style="width:{{ field_ct_rack_left_pdu__value }}%"</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.iab-progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius:1em;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  }

.iab-progress-bar::before {
  content: attr(data-label);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: .5em;
  top: .5em;
  bottom: .5em;  
  /*width:3%;*/
  min-width: 2rem;
  max-width: calc(100% - 1em);
  background-color: #fc7703;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
 }
```

[Rendered progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmqb9.jpg)

When I use the width: attribute in the .iab-progress-bar::before selector the bar expands as expected.

The data-label attribute contains the correct value.

I have tried playing around with the data-label attribute in the width: selector but of course I have not been successful.

Thanks for your time and thoughts.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly, you want the width to be set in relation to the value of the data attribute? I think as things stand with css at the moment you will need to use a couple of lines of JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for your interest.  You are correct, I want the progress bar width to be set to the value of the data-label.  If I manually include something like width: 50%; in the CSS it displays correctly.  I need to figure out how to set it using something like so:

width: (data-label)%;

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. As things stand in browsers at the moment you’ll need JS for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

> Html :

```
<div class= "iab-progress-bar">
<div class="iab-progress-bar_Fill" data-label="20%" style="width:20%" 
</div></div>
```

> Css:

```
.iab-progress-bar {
 position: relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 height: 3em;
 background-color: #111;
 border-radius:1em;
 color: white;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 }

.iab-progress-bar_Fill{
content: attr(data-label);
display: flex;
align-items: center;
position: absolute;
left: .5em;
top: .5em;
bottom: .5em;  
min-width: 2rem;
max-width: calc(100% - 1em);
background-color: #fc7703;
border-radius: 1em;
padding: 1em;
}
```

Now it works dynamically while changing the value

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  I tried it this way before using the current code.  The results are identical.  I believe Drupal Views strips the inline style attribute (I don't see it in the CSS inspector) so I'm looking for an alternative way to set the width: value.

Answer (score 0):

Trying another approach. Here's the CSS:

```
 

     .iab-progress-bar-cont {
     height:25px;
     background-color: gray;
     position: relative;
     border-radius:7px;
     width: 100%;
     color:white;
    }

    .iab-progress-bar-cont::before {
     content: attr(dyn-width);
    }

    .iab-progress-bar-cont .iab-progress-bar-fill {
     position:absolute;
     height: 100%;
     border-radius:7px;
     background-color: red;
     animation: progress-animation 3s forwards;
     
    }


    @keyframes progress-animation {
     0% {width: 0%;}
     100% {width: var(dyn-width);}
    }
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="iab-progress-bar-cont" dyn-width="{{ 
field_ct_rack_right_pdu__value }}%">
<div class="iab-progress-bar-fill" >
</div>
</div>

This CSS code creates a bar and it animates to full width:

@keyframes progress-animation {
 0% {width: 0%;}
 100% {width: 100%;}

This CSS code creates a bar,but does not animate. The correct value is 
being applied to the dyn-width variable (see linked pic): 

@keyframes progress-animation {
0% {width: 0%;}
100% {width: var(dyn-width);}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a6QX.jpg)

Thanks again for your time and thoughts.